# Join table with filtering by date

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join

I have 2 tables. 1st - wallets, 2nd - wallet histories. Now I can make a selection by the sum of all completed deposits/withdrawal for each wallet.

Sql-code looks something like this:

```
SELECT w.*, wh.deposit, wh2.withdrawal, wh3.pending
FROM wallets w
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT wallet_id, SUM(amount) deposit
    FROM wallet_histories
    WHERE type = 'Deposit'
        AND status = 'Completed'
        AND timestamp BETWEEN '2019-08-02 00:00:00+00' AND '2019-08-03 00:00:00+00'
    GROUP BY wallet_id
) wh ON w.id = wh.wallet_id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT wallet_id, SUM(amount) withdrawal
    FROM wallet_histories
    WHERE type = 'Withdrawal'
        AND status = 'Completed'
        AND timestamp BETWEEN '2019-08-02 00:00:00+00' AND '2019-08-03 00:00:00+00'
    GROUP BY wallet_id
) wh2 ON w.id = wh2.wallet_id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT wallet_id, SUM(amount) pending
    FROM wallet_histories
    WHERE status = 'Pending'
    GROUP BY wallet_id
) wh3 ON w.id = wh3.wallet_id
```

Next, I need to make this selection but with filtering by field enabled_at from the table wallets. 
I supposed to make one more condition in WHERE: 
`AND timestamp >= w.enabled_at`
but got error

```
LINE 10:       AND timestamp >= w.enabled_at
                                ^
HINT:  There is an entry for table "w", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
```

How i can avoid this error (maybe fully rebuild query)?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to accomplish would all help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the condition in each subquery.  The results of the aggregations do not have `enabled_at`, so that column is not available in the outer query -- either in the `on` or `where` clauses.

That said, you can drastically simplify your query using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT wallet_id,
       SUM(amount) FILTER (WHERE type = 'Deposit') as deposit
       SUM(amount) FILTER (WHERE type = 'Withdrawal') as withdrawal,
       SUM(amount) FILTER (WHERE status = 'Pending') as pending
FROM wallet_histories
WHERE (type IN ('Deposit', 'Withdrawal') AND
       status = 'Completed' AND
       timestamp >= '2019-08-02' AND
       timestamp < '2019-08-03'
      ) OR
      status = 'Pending'
GROUP BY wallet_id;
```

This might make it easier to add additional conditions.